# Which resource I can use in AliCloud to deploy Apache Beam pipeline, and in AliCloud Do we have datastore if not what is alternative for datastore?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, apache-beam, alibaba-cloud, alibaba-cloud-ecs, alibaba-cloud-function-compute

Currently On GCP I am using Dataflow where I deployed Apache beam pipeline Now I need to deploy same in Ali Cloud is anybody know what will be the available option in Ali cloud to deploy Apache beam pipeline.?
and I am using datastore in Google cloud do we have datastore in Ali is not what database I can use.?

correct resource name from AliCloud for Apache beam pipeline
and datastore alternative in AliCloud

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware if AliCloud supports Apache Spark or Flink to run data processing pipelines, but if yes then you can just leverage Beam Spark or Flink runners for that and execute Beam pipelines in this way there.

Comment: Your post does not answer the question, which means you should post as a comment to the question and delete this answer.

Comment: Disagree. What is the question in your opinion? I believe it was "is anybody know what will be the available option in Ali cloud to deploy Apache beam pipeline.?" And my answer proposed one of the possible ways how to do that. That is why I posted this as an answer, not just a comment.

Comment: **I'm not aware if AliCloud supports Apache Spark or Flink** is not an answer. The OP is asking for the Alibaba service to use, not a recommendation for which software application to install.

Comment: There was a second part of answer. The author is asking about how to run Apache Beam pipeline on AliCloud. One of the option is to use Spark/Flink/etc runners, that Beam supports, to do that if AliCloud provides a way to use Spark/Flink/etc as data processing engines. It's not a perfect answer but, at least, it gives a direction where to follow next. Also, it would be great if you could provide more details about AliCloud/Beam integration if you already have such experience.